# oauth - sharing client_secret

Tags: oauth, jwt, clientcredential

Suppose I have 2 services registered at the Auth Server:

1. Service A, with `client-id=service-a-id` and `client_secret=service-a-secret`
2. Service B, with `client-id=service-b-id` and `client_secret=service-b-secret`

Auth Server issues a JWT

Now service A wants to call service B and to use a `client credentials` flow.
Which of the services should share its `client_secret` shared with another?
If Service A uses its own secrets to send request to auth server and get a token, then `service-a-secret` should be shared with the Service B, so that it could verify the JWT signature?

I am quite disoriented because `secret` assumes not to be shared to anyone but auth server and owner application. However, if Service B wants to verify the token without calling Auth Server, what should it do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that Auth Server signs JWT with its own keys and you do not need to know anyone's secret to validate the JWT. While it is pretty evident, it was not quite evident to me from the references.

So, `client_secret` MUST NOT be shared to anyone but Auth Server and Application, owning its secret.